# renaming files in a directory by adding string to a list of string using Python 2.7.8

Tags: file, concatenation, rename

Im trying to add the file extension back to a file path and filename after deleting the last 10 characters of the file's name.

Code so far:

```
rootDir = "C\\Users\\Documents\\New"

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(rootDir):
for fileys in filenames:
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, fileys)
    filesplit = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
    fileext = filesplit
    os.rename(fullpath, fullpath[:-5] + fileext) #line that has error
```

What my error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Student/Downloads/App.py", line 28, in 
    os.rename(fullpath, fullpath[:-10] + (s + fileext for s in fullpath))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'generator' objects

I see that the issue is that I am trying to concatenate a string and generator, but when i tried:

```
os.rename (fullpath, fullpath[:10] + fileext)
```

The error i receive is that I cannot concatenate a tuple and a string.

So how do I add on the file extension to the fullpath after i remove the last 10 characters of the filename while renaming the file.

Thanks

Comment: `fileext = filesplit` looks fishy. `os.path.splitext()` returns a tuple of the file name and the extension. Perhaps you want `fileext = filesplit[1]` there. Also `fullpath[:-5]` is operating on the original `fullpath`, with the extension still attached, which may not be what you want. Maybe `filesplit[0][:-5] + filesplit[1]` is what you're after for creating the new name?

Comment: So i tried this out:

New Code:
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(rootDir)
    for fileys in filenames:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, fileys)
        filesplit = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
        fileext = filesplit[1]
        os.rename(fullpath, filesplit[0][:-5] + filesplit[1])

However, it still did not work. Error I got was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Student/Downloads/App.py", line 28, in <module>
    os.rename(fullpath, filesplit[0][:-5] + filesplit[1])
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists